# Can we use blenrig 5 on blender 2.9x, or has it become obsolete?

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on

I want to use blenrig for my character in blender 2.9x and upcoming versions,
If blenrig is obsolete, then suggest me similar industry standard rigging add-on